# dc.js group.top(5) not working in chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

i am trying to display top 5 country based on revenue

i tried feeding in chart its not working

```
.group(countryGrp.top(10))
```

but when i tried `console.log(countryGrp.top(10))` i can see the values though

```
var country = data.dimension(function(d){return d.PName});
var countryGrp = lead.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
            return d.Amount;
        });

var leadBarChart = dc.barChart("#country-chart")
        leadBarChart.width(500).height(450).transitionDuration(750)
                .margins({
                    top : 20,
                    right : 10,
                    bottom : 80,
                    left : 50
                })
                .dimension(country)
                .group(countryGrp.top(10))
                .ordinalColors([ "#1F77B4" ]).elasticY(true).centerBar(true)
                .title(function(d) {
                    return d.Amount;
                }).gap(6).xUnits(function() {
                    return 2;
                })
                .x(d3.scale.linear())
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true).xAxis().ticks(5)
                .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```

i am getting this error uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  can any one help me out here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

So `group.top(N)` doesn't return a group object; it returns an array.  You need to supply a group for the group argument.

Unfortunately the bar chart does not currently support [capping](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#cap-mixin) but what you can do is prefilter the data as explained here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted

Basically you will create a "fake group" which has an `.all()` function which returns only the items you want.

I am planning to fix `.data()` so that it works for bar charts:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584

(and it would also be nice to support capping) but for now I think you are stuck with the "fake group" workaround.

Please comment here if you can't get this to work, or add you example to the wiki linked above if you do get it to work!

Comment: Does barchart support capping now ?

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't been added to the core library. It's easy to cap the number of bars with a fake group but the "others grouper" is the more difficult feature to simulate outside the library. If you don't care about the "others" bar you can use @alexfigtree's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use something like the following:

```
function getTops(source_group) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            return source_group.top(5);
        }
    };
}
var fakeGroup = getTops(groupToFindTopsFor);
```

You can then use .group(fakeGroup) to properly chart your data.